# Is Experience Replay like dreaming?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, deep-rl, experience-replay

Drawing parallels between Machine Learning techniques and a human brain is a dangerous operation. When it is done successfully, it can be a powerful tool for vulgarisation, but when it is done with no precaution, it can lead to major misunderstandings.

I was recently attending a conference where the speaker described Experience Replay in RL as a way of making the net "dream".
I'm wondering how true this assertion is. The speaker argued that a dream is a random addition of memories, just as experience replay. However, I doubt the brain remembers its dream or either learns from it. What is your analysis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The speaker argued that a dream is a random addition of memories, just as experience replay.

The speaker is taking some liberties due to a general lack of scientific understanding of what dreams are. We don't even have strong consensus on why sleep is a necessary feature of animals, let alone what part dreaming plays in it. However, there are some widely-accepted theories, [with supporting evidence, that dreams are part of a learning and memorisation process](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3079906/). Studies that manipulate sleep or dreaming have shown changes in the speed that skills are learned for example.

Experience replay in reinforcement learning is a far more precise and well-understood affair, whereby individual time steps that occurred in the past are visited and re-assessed in light of current knowledge about long-term value, at random. If dreams were really like experience replay as it is practiced in RL today, then they would consist of a random jumble of tiny seemingly inconsequential events strung together, and all taken very exactly from the events of the past day. [*Sometimes* dreams do contain content like this](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0185262), but typically the content is far more varied.

Taken with a large dose of artistic license, then yes, the speaker is referring to [real theories and conjectures about dreaming, that do have scientific support](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4704085/). Although it is equally good to draw parallels between dreams and a higher-level *management* of the memory or experience replay data - which items to replay, and which to keep, depending on what is salient about the information. For instance, there is [good evidence that dreams help filter what is *forgotten*](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/37/3/464), and also evidence that events associated with strong emotional state are more likely to feature in dreams.

It is important to separate the speaker's analogy, and any suggestion that a current reinforcement learning agent has a subjective experience. We are still a long way away from anything like that, and other similar use of a dreaming metaphor in machine learning - e.g. "Deep Dream" - is equally not an assertion that the devices are having an experience of any kind.